# Automatically mounting LUKS encrypted volume during boot

Tags: boot, luks, autostart

Running RHEL 7.9, my root partition is LUKS encrypted so during system boot I am prompted at the console for the passphrase to continue booting;  that part is fine.

Once system is booted, in `/etc/fstab` I have a mount `/dev/sdc1 /data` where that block device is LUKS encrypted.

I can use the GNOME DISKS utility to unlock it and mount it but that becomes a second process, and a manual one I have to remember every time the system reboots... I also have to log in at the console and run the `gnome-disks` utility to mount my `/data` folder... which is terabytes and my OS disk root partition is only 600gb so the problem that quickly arises is the root partition filling up if `/data` doesn't get mounted.

How, under RHEL 7.9, can the **automatic** unlocking and mounting of a LUKS encrypted *disk* be made to happen during boot time?  *So it then mounts like any other [unencrypted] disk specified in `/etc/fstab`?*

Answer (score 3):

If you are comfortable with storing your encryption key on the (encrypted) root partition, this is doable. Create the file `/etc/crypttab.keyfile` containing your key. I have then used something like

```
# blkid /dev/sdc1
/dev/sda1: UUID="1249cb86-92a3-4e3b-8299-828a119fb3d1" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" 
PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="75cf0a0e-0f4d-43c8-b8f5-fa26ab197ddc"
# echo "luks-1249cb86-92a3-4e3b-8299-828a119fb3d1 UUID=1249cb86-92a3-4e3b-8299- 
828a119fb3d1 /etc/crypttab.keyfile luks,discard" >> /etc/crypttab
# cryptsetup -v luksOpen /dev/sdc1 luks-1249cb86-92a3-4e3b-8299-828a119fb3d1 \
--key-file=/etc/crypttab.keyfile
```

Your device will be decrypted automagically at boot time and can be mounted through fstab.

Always keep a copy of your encryption key stored safely on another media. Lose it and your disk is gone.

Comment: Ok, that is waaay better than my approach ...

Comment: your instructions got me part way to my goal, of which I am entering as the answer.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

here's how I got it to work

```
dd   if=/dev/urandom  of=/root/crypttab.key  bs=1024   count=4
chmod  400  /root/crypttab.key
cryptsetup    luksAddkey   UUID=###   /root/crypttab.key
cryptsetup   -v luksOpen   UUID=###   /root/crypttab.key
# edit /etc/cryptab manually, each line having:
    <volume-name>   <encrypted-device>   <key-file>   <options>
```

- UUID=### is of the luks locked partition as shown in gnome disks or lsblk
- don't use `/dev/sda1` or the *by-name* convention because as disks come and go or move in the system your luks encrypted volume could become sdb or sdc and it'll fail; using UUID is reliable
- the `<volume name>` I believe can be anything
- I suspect all the conventions allowed in `/etc/fstab` column 1 for mounting can be used here such as uuid, label, scsi-id... refer to contents under `/dev/disk/`
- for the manual editing of `/etc/crypttab`

  - will be a blank file nothing crypttab [or luks] related has been done yet
  - this file cannot be renamed nor moved to something else
  - should have permissions root.root and `-rw-------`
  - each line for unlocking a given luks locked device has 4 columns

    - https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/crypttab.html
    - ```
           <volume-name>   <encrypted-device>   <key-file>   <options>
      ```
  - an example could be

    - `scratch  UUID=abc123  /root/crypttab.key   luks`
    - the 4th column for  would be `luks`
- the `cryptsetup -v`  adds the key file to LUKS, which is independent of the original passphrase used to LUKS encrypt the volume
- the `cryptsetup -v` will prompt for the existing passphrase, so the key I believe is based off the passphrase
- if the `/root/crypttab.key` is compromised, don't know if the original passphrase is safe, I suspect it probably is.
- if the `/root/crypttab.key` is compromised or lost, just need to delete the corresponding entry in /etc/crypttab and revert to using the passphrase or redo cryptsetup with new key
- the `/root/crypttab.key` file can be deleted, as long as you know the original (or current) passphrase used to LUKS encrypt you can unlock and get your data
- once this is setup, simply clicking the unlock button in gnome disks utility will unlock the volume without prompting for the passphrase, which is really what needs to happen
- the entry in `/etc/fstab` of mounting the [encrypted] device is actually independent of crypt; nothing LUKS related happens in `/etc/fstab`
- the `/root/crypttab.key`  file can be named anything and located anywhere
- the UUID to be used is that of the locked LUKS partition, before it has been unlocked.
- with entries in `/etc/crypttab` present the GNOME disks utility will recognize that and the gnome disks will allow you to change the existing passphrase and it is good enough to indicate it will also update or respect the existing key files.

Comment: Got this working. Some typos to mind of:
.......
"luksAddKey (not luksAddkey)"
.......
"cryptsetup -v luksOpen UUID=### <mount label, not full path>"